# CX_Freeze Do not Set ICON

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am not able to compile with Cx_freeze, When I put the item "icon" nothing happens.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [Executable(script ='RabbiGet.py',base=base, icon ='icone.ico')]
includefiles = ['icone.ico','Softplan.png','rabbit.png','saj.png','down.png']

setup(name='RabbiGet',
      version='1.0',
      description='RabbitMQ downs',
      author = "Patric Guisolffi",
      options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles,'packages': ["os","sys","ctypes","win32con"]}},
      executables=executables
      )'''
```

Comment: Maybe you could post more description on how you've tried and what happened.

Comment: What's the icon?the exe icon?Or the tkinter `.iconbitmap`?

Comment: exe icon, I can't compile with exe icon

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
include_files = ['Softplan.png','rabbit.png','saj.png','down.png']

options = {
    'build_exe': {
    'include_msvcr': True,
    'build_exe': 'name_exe',
    'include_files': include_files,
    }
}

setup(
    name="RabbiGet",
    version="1.0",
    author = "Patric Guisolffi",
    description='RabbitMQ downs',
    executables=executables,
    options=options,
)
```

Comment: My problem is in "icon" I can't set the icon, can you help-me ? :)